# How can I find existing mounting holes after the wall was repaired?

Tags: walls, hole

Client forgot to tell workers to leave mounting holes open so they ended up patching all the holes.  These holes are for a heavy wall ornament which used screw inserts.  Is there any way I can either wet the wall to see where the previous holes are located or use a stud finder to detect them?  Thanks!

The client doesn't know what the screw inserts where made from, I was considering the Walabot but I don't know if it will see a difference in the from the spackled hole verse normal drywall.  Yes once I know where one is I can find the other two holes.

I'm not the owner, it would have been so easy if they had just put a toothpick or something in the holes before spackling.  I was at the location last week for another job but didn't have a chance to inspect the surface in detail. I'm going there next week again, just wanted to get some ideas before I go.  I might try using a powerful light held at an angle if the other suggested methods don't work.  The owner claims that the Soffit is brick.  Not sure why they would have made a Soffit out of brick, we'll see.  Seems rather expensive for no real benefit.

[image]

Comment: Were there plastic inserts in the wall that would have left bumps in the finished surface? If no, what kind of mounting system was used? What do you consider a "screw insert"? If they're metal, you should be able to find them with a magnet. If they were proud of the surface, you should be able to find them with a long straight edge.

Comment: If heavy, finding studs and using them to hold screws is good.  Drywall is good for light cheap stuff, but once money starts adding up for heavy stuff, screws into studs is the way to go.

Comment: If the inserts were steel, a magnet might find them, but that will also find every drywall screw or nail. Hope for some reference pictures to give an area to search. If not steel, some sort of wall scanner might work - I haven't experience using any that would, though.

Comment: Once you have found one, then the pattern should help you find the others, also if the first one is a false (ie drywall screw etc) then the pattern won't match...

Comment: Are you the homeowner?

Comment: One thing I have done to find studs in a stud-and-drywall wall when I didn't have a stud finder or hammer was to very gently run my fingers on the wall. The sound of the fingers brushing over the plaster used to fill nail holes was slightly different than the sound over the unmodified drywall surface, even when primed and painted. Very often I was able to find the studs just by listening for the different sound. Maybe such a thing might work for your mounting holes.